# Get total from several tables and queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 6 tables of data.
I have 10 different queries that produce a table like this

Any idea of an query? Im a begginer so it's kinda hard.

Comment: Total percentage must have sum=1.0... if you add separate percentages as shown in "Result" the sum will be 10, not 1 - so it will not be total percentage, it will be something else.

Comment: in the inner query, use a UNION to get the output from individual tables. Wrap this inner query with a Select and perform the operations you wish

Comment: @BlackSwan Are you suggesting him to summarize boots with crocodiles?

Comment: The total percentage WILL have sum = 1 :-) the query already have that into account. Can you suggest one query based on what i said?

Comment: Those values were made up, so its normal that doesnt sum 1

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want `union all` and `group by`:

```
with q1 as (
      <query1>
     ),
     q2 as (
      <query2>
     ),
     . . .
select company, sum(total_percentage)
from ((select q1.* from q1) union all
      (select q2.* from q2) union all
      . . .
      (select q10.* from q10)
     ) q
group by company;
```

That said, I would be surprised if six different queries are needed for the initial results.  You might want to ask another question if you want to simplify that (however, provide simpler versions of the queries for such a question).

Comment: Can you write an example considering 2 queries? I have errors in syntax